# javascript/jquery- how to obtain all possible values in a drop down box or list box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to obtain all the values stored in a list box/drop down box.

I am currently using following code to obtain name, type, multiple attribute and values--

```
     $(jQuery('input, select, textarea', $(this).parent('form'))).each(function() {


            var textmsg=" Element # " + (count+1) + "...Name of this input element = " + $(this).attr('name') + " multiplechoice-" +  $(this).attr('multiple');
            textmsg= textmsg + "...Also, for this element, the value is " + $(this).val() + " and type =" +  $(this).attr('type');
            alert (textmsg);

    });
```

But the jquery call $(this).val() retrieves only the currently selected value in a list box (and not all values). The same thing happens when I use the above code in a drop down box. How do I obtain all the values stored in a list/drop down box? If it is not possible to do this using jquery, then can this be done using pure javascript? (I have a reference to that form element which can be used in pure javascript...)

Comment: `var textmsg;` declare it outside the loop(each) block.

Comment: @ManseUK - thank you, i will keep your comments in mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a list of your options you need to declare a variable outside of the loop

```
var listofoptions = new Array();

$("#id option").each(function()
{
    // add $(this).val() to your list
    listofoptions.push($(this).val());

});

// do what you want with listofoptions
```

Comment: @ManseUK- I have one more question related to this query--- i have a scenario where I dont have the ID of the select(list or drop down)-- is it possible to use a selector for getting all options within the loop I have given in my question? Thanks...

Comment: @Arvind you can use any selector to get a group or single object

Answer (score 0):

You can get all fields inside form using following code

```
        var formFields = $("form")[0];
         var textmsg = "";
         for ( var i = 0, len = formFields.length; i < len; i++ ) {


         textmsg +=" Element # " + (i+1) + "...Name of this input element = " +  $(formFields[i]).attr('name') + " multiplechoice-" +  $(formFields[i]).attr('multiple');
 textmsg= textmsg + "...Also, for this element, the value is " + $(formFields[i]).val() + " and type =" +  $(formFields[i]).attr('type');
        }
        document.write( textmsg );
```

[jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/NXFVE/2/)

Comment: I would check your jsfiddle - the output is all over the place and contains lots of `undefined` errors

Comment: Check HTML code some of the fields dont have name attribute. and for some of them $(formFields[i]).attr('multiple') is undefined.

Comment: `multiple` is undefined on all elements !!! I have update your jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/NXFVE/3/ the output is cleaner and easier to read (havent touched the JS)

Comment: @ManseUK  type is undefined for select